# Можно ли внести отдельным файлом изменения в шаблон wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Так как темы бывает обновляются, то все вносимые изменения в нее сбрасываются до начальных. можно конечно вручную все это снова вносить. но со временем такие изменения накапливаются.
можно ли попытаться внести подобные изменения отдельным файлом по аналогии как создают дочерние темы?

Comment: а почему дочерние темы не подходят? Они как раз работаю как вы и описали или я не понял сути вопроса

Comment: скорее не понял сути. я хочу в свою установленную тему внести некоторые поправки, в общем частично где-то добавить иконки у мета данных записей или вовсе что то убрать, изменить вид аватарки автора записи. когда тема обновляется все эти изменения сбрасываются, а в раздел customize можно вносить только стили css, но не менять сами строчки в шаблоне

Comment: Ну так у вас и спрашивают, а чем вас дочерние темы не устраивает? Переопределили шаблон и пусть себе тема обновляется. Они для этого и существуют, чтоб внесенные изменения не исчезали после обновления родительской темы.

Comment: так а как это сделать, я спрашиваю уже? создать родительскую тему со своим набором?

Comment: Открываете гугл и пишите «wordpress child theme” смотрите ссылку на codex и изучаете. Подсказка, для создания дочерней темы достаточно 2 файлов style.css и functions.php

Comment: Скиньте начало содержимого style.css из вашей темы (там есть комментарий с названием темы, создателем и т.д.)

Comment: да хоть всю тему могу скинуть https://github.com/ArrayHQ/atomic-blocks-theme но в ней я многое изменяю в файле https://github.com/ArrayHQ/atomic-blocks-theme/blob/master/inc/template-tags.php какие то строчки удаляя и прописывая новые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файл functions.php можно пока ничего не добавлять. Потом в нем подключите стили и скрипты.

style.css для дочерней темы

```
    /*
    Theme Name: Atomic Blocks Child
    Description: Atomic Blocks Child Theme
    Template: atomic-blocs
    Version: 1.0.0
    Text Domain: atomic-blocks-child
    */
```

Все это создаете в директории: /wp-content/themes/atomic-blocks-child/

Comment: мне файл content-meta надо изменить, не стили, а именно строчки, удалив категории отображение например, заменив слово теги на иконку, вот такой файл как создать для дочерней темы, тогда уж?

Comment: После того, как создали дочернюю тему, скопируйте этот файл с родительской темы в дочернюю и измените его, дочерняя тема должна быть активна. И потом вносите в этом файле изменения. Если файл вложен в какую-то директорию, повторите вложенность